# Why isn't VS Code registering my Javascipt code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Forgive me if I don't really know how to articulate this question, as I'm not sure how to describe the problem (new at this). I'm doing a coding boot camp with my brother. We're working on the same assignment.

[The image is of some js code he wrote. I wrote the same exact line of code, we both saved it in the exact type of files and mine is all colored and registering fine in the browser. His is not. We have no idea why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCe4q.png)

Comment: We both copy and pasted the exact HTML code as well and saved them both the exact same way. His js isn't registering

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 1):

The white dot says there are unsaved changes, make sure to press STRG+s while in the filte to save it. Or rightclick on it and save.

Comment: haha thank you Max! We figured it out. Can't wait to look back on this question and laugh